# How to list all fields in elasticsearch6

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

We have upgraded the ELK2 to ELK6, in ELK2, we treat every kind of logs as a type, like nginx log, mysql log, every type of log has own fields mapping. It's easy to list all fields of a type, like `GET /logstash-2018.05.08/_mapping/mysql`

As we known, Elasticsearch6 has remove concept of type, in a index, our log data only has one type called `doc`. If I use `GET /logstash-2018.05.08/_mapping/doc`, it will return all fields mapping including all log type, it's hard to identify which field is belong to mysql or nginx.

And I still want to list all fields mapping of a specific type. How to do that?

Comment: Actually, you should have indexed each type into its own index, or modify the mapping so that all fields are in their own structure, i.e. one object structure for mysql and another distinct one for nginx.

Comment: Yes, it should be, the problem is we have to change many filebeat configuration in many client server, it also needs a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

I have one idea about that but I'm not sure if this will be helpful for you.

Guys from Elastic are proposing [index per document type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_index_per_document_type) as one of alternatives to mapping types. Maybe it would be possible for you to move to separate indices and have:

```
/logstash-2018.05.08-mysql
/logstash-2018.05.08-nginx
```

then you would be able to get fields similar as before:

```
/logstash-2018.05.08-mysql/_mapping/doc
/logstash-2018.05.08-nginx/_mapping/doc
```

and later you can add alias to all this indexes to search on all of them if you needed:

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions" : [
    { "add" : { "index" : "logstash-2018.05.08-*", "alias" : "logstash-2018.05.08" } }
  ]
}
```

This way from search perspective you can still search under `/logstash-2018.05.08` but you will have separate indices and mappings for each source as previously.

Comment: Thanks, it is  a ultimate way, if I can not find out a better solution, cause re-indexing all log data needs to change filebeat configurations on client server, our log data comes from many servers. it is not easy for us.